# Speeding up SQL query in R for time-series data

Tags: r, performance, sqlite, subquery, rsqlite

I have a database which contains historic river levels and rainfall data. There is a 'Levels' table which has attributes including the date at which a measurement is taken, and the river level on that date. And also a 'Rainfall' table which, similarly, has attributes including date and rainfall on that date.

I want to run some regressions on this data (in R) so I am trying to get my data into the format:

```
Date | Level | Level yesterday | Level 2 days ago | ... | Level 5 days ago | Rainfall | Rainfall yesterday | Rainfall 2 days ago | ... | Rainfall 5 days ago
```

This format means that all the data needed to predict the current level is contained within a single row.

I have some (very ugly) code that will do this but it is too slow.

The following code tries to select just 1 previous day's level, from just 1 gauge, in only years since 2000. (For more history of levels and rainfall I simply include more sub-queries.)

```
  SELECT level, rainfall,
  (
  SELECT K.level
  FROM Levels as K 
  WHERE L.gauge_id = K.gauge_id
  AND 
  julianday(L.year || '-' || substr('00'||L.month,-2) || '-' ||substr('00'||L.day,-2)) - 
  julianday(K.year || '-' || substr('00'||K.month,-2) || '-' ||substr('00'||K.day,-2))
  = -1
  LIMIT 1
  ) as L1
FROM Levels as L JOIN Gauges as G ON (L.gauge_id = G.id)
JOIN Rainfall as R ON (R.station_id = G.nearestStat)
WHERE L.year=R.year AND L.month=R.month AND L.day=R.day
AND L.gauge_id = 208006
AND L.year>2000
```

This hugely simplified and reduced query takes about 30min to execute in R (using ans=dbGetQuery(db, query)). This only returns ~6000 rows, whereas the complete dataset that I would like will be ~80 million rows.

How can I speed up this query so that I can get the data in the format that I need in a reasonable amount of time?

Edit: 
Example input data

```
Levels Table
gauge_id  year  month   day   level
201001    1957   6       22    0.485
201001    1957   6       23    0.759
201001    1957   6       24    0.864
565753    2001   12      4     1.984

Rainfall Table
station_id  year  month   day   rainfall
123456      1957   6       22   0
123456      1957   6       23   75.4
123456      1957   6       24   20.2
987654      1986   1       16   0

Gauges Table
gauge_id    nearest_station
201001       123456
565753       764892
876544       987654
```

Example output data:

```
gauge_id    station_id    Level   Level-1    Level-2   Rainfall   Rainfall-1
201001       123456       0.864    0.759      0.485    20.2        75.4
```

Comment: can you add example of your initial data and example of how the data should look at end?

Comment: Is your data always in three consecutive days? What do you want in case only two consecutive days are available? What should happen when four consecutive days occur? What should happen for the first and second of three consecutive days?

Comment: Agreeing with minem, please provide your sample data in SQL syntax (i.e. some lines of ìnsert into table values(...);` accompanied by the database structure (lines of `create table ...`). Use a tailored toy database if you do not want to show all your data.

Comment: I would try to get each table separately and then transform the data in R, but that is probably because I am more familiar with R. How much time does it take to query all the necessary tables?

Comment: Do you have appropriate indexes defined in your database?